# MBR-раздел при установке Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, установка

При установке Windows на жёсткий диск говорят, что так как на нём находится MBR-раздел, то на него нельзя установить. Что делать?

Comment: Первое, что пришло в голову - не ставить Win 10. Но ответ такой: http://prostocomp.net/sistema/problemy-s-ustanovkoj-windows-10-na-mbr-razdel-oshibka-ustanovka-windows-na-dannyj-disk-nevozmozhna.html

Comment: @DimXenon Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно переформатировать диск с использованием другого стиля разделов. Для этого можете прочесть данную статью, будет полезной: [Программа установки Windows: использование стиля разделов MBR или GPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn336946.aspx).

Зачем преобразовывать MBR и GPT в Windows 10?

> MBR поддерживает разделы объёмом до 2 ТБ. Что это означает? Например, если размер логического диска составляет 3 ТБ, то 1 ТБ будет определён как неразмеченная область в Windows 10 и вы не сможете её использовать. Для преодоления этого ограничения, пользователям необходимо преобразовать MBR в GPT.

Если уж так получилось, что у Вас уже установлена Windows 10 и Вы хотите изменить стиль разделов, то читайте далее, как это сделать.

### Как преобразовывать MBR и GPT в Windows 10

Для пользователей Windows 10 существует пара способов преобразования MBR в GPT и обратно. Рассмотрим способы более подробно.

---

**Управление дисками (Disk Management)** – это встроенный инструмент Windows 10, который даёт вам возможность изменять (создавать, удалять, увеличивать, сокращать) разделы, преобразовывать их в GPT или MBR. Воспользуйтесь данным инструментом:

> Откройте окно кликнув «Этот компьютер» > «Управление» > «Управление дисками»

Правой кнопкой мышки укажите диск, который необходимо преобразовать (например, «Диск 0»). Во всплывающем окне, вы увидите неактивную функцию «Преобразовать в GPT диск». С помощью этого инструмента можно преобразовать в MBR или GPT только если на диске нет разделов. Вам нужно удалить все разделы на Диске 0 и после этого преобразовывать MBR в GPT и обратно.

---

**Командная строка** – это встроенный инструмент Windows 10, который может упорядочить разделы и преобразовывать MBR в GPT. Командная строка позволяет преобразовывать MBR в GPT и обратно, только если на диске, с которым вы планируете работать нет разделов. Итак, делаем следующее:

> Кликните «Пуск» > введите «Командная строка» в строке поиска и нажмите
>   «Ввод», чтобы открыть окно; Введите «list disk» и нажмите «Ввод»;
>   Введите «select disk N» и нажмите «Ввод». «N» – это номер диска,
>   который вы хотите преобразовать (например, «Диск 0»); Введите «clean»
>   и нажмите «Ввод» чтобы удалить все разделы или тома на выбранном
>   диске; Введите «convert mbr» и нажмите «Ввод» чтобы завершить
>   преобразование с GPT в MBR формат.

### С осторожностью!

**Оба указанных метода дают возможность преобразовать MBR диск в GPT и обратно. Но оба метода требуют удаления всех разделов с диска, и Вы находитесь под риском утери данных. Поэтому, прежде чем запустить процесс конвертации, сделайте резервную копию всех данных, которые будут удалены, а затем восстановите их.**

Comment: а если а уменя стоит 8 , а хочу 10 поставить , то что надо ?

Comment: Можете просто обновить систему стандартными утилитами системы, без установки по новой. А потом после обновления до 10 через очистку диска удалить файлы от прошлой системы. Надежно и безболезненно. Я так делал с 8.1 на 10, буквально месяц тому назад.