# Как преобразовать из mbr в gpt

Tags: windows-10, установка

Нужно установить windows 10, но при установке пишет,что на диске используется mbr-таблица.
Как можно преобразовать диск из mbr в gpt без потери данных?

Comment: Этот вопрос дублирует вот этот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539423/mbr-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-windows-10

Comment: @Oxyd где в той теме сказано про то, как преобразовать из mbr в gpt без потери данных? я такого там не нашёл

Comment: Да, тогда так: https://medium.com/levashove/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-mbr-%D0%B2-gpt-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-windows-10-603496208d8f
Актуально для 10-й винды: 
`mbr2gpt /validate /disk:[номер диска] /allowFullOS`
`mbr2gpt /convert /disk:[номер диска] /allowFullOS`
Номер диска смотреть в Управление компьютером → Управление дисками.

Comment: @Oxyd у меня ещё не установлена windows 10, откуда мне взять mbr2gpt ?

Comment: Ну раз так, брать загрузочную флешку с линуксом и попробовать конвертнуть при помощи `gdisk`. Проблема может быть в том, что после последнего раздела, должно быть небольшое место секторов тридцать, для второй копии GUID Table. Но такое бывает далеко не всегда.

Comment: @Oxyd может ещё как-то можно по другому?

Comment: Ну, теоретически, это должны уметь всякие Acronis-ы, но это варез, сами понимаете.